# Using electron webContent function to fire an event based on the class name

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a button in my electron application with class name "send":

```
<a class="send></a>
```

I don't now any details about functions associated with this button class. All I know is when the user press the button, it will send a message(like posting a tweet online). Now I want to define a shortcut key to trigger this event:

```
const getMainWindow = () => {
  return BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0]
}

const getMainWindowWebContents = () => {
  const win = getMainWindow()
  if (win) {
    return win.webContents
  } else {
    return {}
  }
}

  {
    label: 'Send Post',
    accelerator: 'CommandOrControl + s',
    click () {
      getMainWindowWebContents()...// here can I use executeJavaScript()???          
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to simulate button press in electron after pressing the shortcut key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to simulate mouse click on your `class="send"` button. To simulate input events use the `webContents`and `sendInputEvent(event)` function.

For mouse clicks simulation, use following example:

```
contents.sendInputEvent({type:'mouseDown', x:300, y: 250, button:'left', clickCount: 1});
contents.sendInputEvent({type:'mouseUp', x:300, y: 250, button:'left', clickCount: 1});
```

Read more about it [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md), you have other input types as well.

Comment: i dont get why x=300 and y=250, how to put values for them?